# collection Counter - How to eliminate counting characters " ' " in a word

Tags: python, python-3.x, counter

I wrote a script to find the longest word in a file/dictionary.
However in English language are used apostrophe " ' " , I'd like to skip counting it.

```
from collections import Counter
import time

words = open('english').read().splitlines()

time_before = time.time()

k = Counter(words)

longest = max(k, key=len)
print('The longest word in Dictionary is:', longest, 'has' , len(longest), 'characters')

time_after = time.time()
time_taken = time_after - time_before
print ( 'Longest word found in: ' , time_taken)
print(".......................")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so for starters, there's no reason to use a `Counter` here, you're not actually counting anything (unless for some reason your dictionary file has duplicate words)

you should be able to filter words out with a comprehension that checks if they contain apostrophes:

```py
import time

with open('english') as f:
    words = f.read().splitlines()

time_before = time.time()

filtered = (word for word in words if "'" not in word)
longest = max(filtered, key=len)
print('The longest word in Dictionary is:', longest, 'has' , len(longest), 'characters')

time_after = time.time()
time_taken = time_after - time_before
print ( 'Longest word found in: ' , time_taken)
print(".......................")
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the key you're using for `max()`:

```
longest = max(k, key=lambda s:len(letter for letter in s if letter != "'"))
```

You can of course customize this solution to exclude more letters, or only include specific things, or etc.

Answer (score 0):

To exclude the apostrophe and all characters after it in the count of the word length:

```
max(k, key=lambda word: len(word.split("'")[0]))
```

Answer (score -1):

hi you could just replace single quote with none then start counting.

```
txt = "hi it's me"
x = txt.replace("'", "")
print(x)
```